# how to change the order of the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

```
house_prices_borough %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = long,
         y = lat,
         group = group,
         fill = Value,
         label = Area,)) +
geom_polygon(color="white")+
theme_void()+
theme(title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    legend.position = "right")+
scale_fill_viridis_d(name = paste("Average House Prices in London"),
                   direction = -1) +
labs(title = "House prices in London",
   subtitle = "December 2017",
   caption = "Source:land registry",
   color = "Value")
```

I am having trouble with the legend / key. As you can see, I am getting two sets of colour sequences, so my map is not numerically sequential. Is there any way I can make it sequential (i.e. lighter colours indicate cheaper prices and darker colours indicate more expensive houses)?

[image]

Comment: From your image I would guess that your `Value` column is a character instead of a numeric. Therefore I would suggest to convert it to a numeric.

Comment: @stefan I dont understand because I am a beginner so could you please explain more specifically ?

Comment: Look at `class(house_prices_borough$Value)` - the class should be numeric. But based on your legend it is probably `character` or `factor`. If it is character, use `house_prices_borough$Value <- as.numeric(house_prices_borough$Value)`. If it is a factor, use `house_prices_borough$Value <- as.numeric(as.character(house_prices_borough$Value))`. This will change your column to `numeric` class and should make your legend much more manageable if you re-run the plot with the `numeric` data.